# Issue with 2D Ray Casting in c# [NOT unity 3D]

Tags: c#, 2d, raycasting

I am making a game in 2D in C#, with my own rendering engine i made with c# and OpenGL. Now im making Enemys. Its a stealth-like game, so i need to know if the enemy's can see the player. This can be done using raycasting. I implemented it, but its slow, to slow. let say i have around 200 objects and 200 rays. each ray checks 50 times for collision on the way with a small collision box (x pos, ypos, 1,1). now that are 200 * 200 * 50 collision checks. Even with multithreading and the cpu at 100% usage(i7 4810mq, 3.8ghz, quadcore, multithreading), the game runs at a terrible 4.1 fps. i need to optimize my code, but don't know how. I need to optimize the raycasting  and not the game. so not: check if an object is out of range and leave it out, merge multiple collision boxes into 1 etc. code:

```
public class RayCast
{
    private int maxSteps;
    private bool hit = false;
    private Box tester;
    private float[] linex, liney;

    private string[] tags;
    private Box target;

    public RayCast(int maxSteps)
    {
        tester = target = new Box(0,0,0,0);
        this.maxSteps = maxSteps;
        linex = new float[maxSteps];
        liney = new float[maxSteps];
        tags = new string[maxSteps];

        for(int i = 0; i < maxSteps; i++)
        {
            linex[i] = 0;
            liney[i] = 0;
            tags[i] = "";
        }
    }

    public void CastRay(float startx, float starty, float velx, float vely, float steps)
    {
        float xx = startx;
        float yy = starty;

        if(steps > maxSteps)steps = maxSteps;
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("linex,liney: " + linex[i] + "," + liney[i]);
            linex[i] = xx;
            liney[i] = yy;
            xx += velx;
            yy += vely;
        }
    }

    public void CheckRay(Sprite[] s)
    {
        hit = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSteps; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
            {
                tester.Set(linex[i], liney[i],0.01f, 0.01f);
                if (tester.Collides(s[j].GetRectangle()))
                {
                    target.Set(s[j].GetRectangle().X, s[j].GetRectangle().Y, s[j].GetRectangle().Width, s[j].GetRectangle().Height);
                    target.SetTag(s[j].GetTag());
                    hit = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (hit) break;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool GetHit()
    {
        return hit;
    }
    public Box GetTarget()
    {
        return target;
    }
}
```

and the use of it in the game:

```
private void RayCast()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (player.isLeft()) rc.CastRay(player.GetX() + player.GetWidth(), player.GetY() + 0.3f, -0.12f, 0f, 50);
            else rc.CastRay(player.GetX(), player.GetY(), 0.12f, 0f, 50);
            rc.CheckRay(walls);
        }

        if (rc.GetHit()) Console.WriteLine("RayCast did HIT [" + rc.GetTarget().GetTag() + "] @ [" + rc.GetTarget().GetX() + "," + rc.GetTarget().GetY() + "," + rc.GetTarget().GetW() + "," + rc.GetTarget().GetH() + "]");
        else Console.WriteLine("RayCast did NOT");
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance,

cody

Comment: A ray is a line of an infinite length (or length bounded by the wall). Instead of making many little bounding boxes, why not just check if the ray intersects the bounding boxes of the sprites? Cast the ray for its entire length, then using the equation of a line, you can determine if the bounding boxes of the sprites intersect the ray or not. You've reduced 2 million checks to 20.

Comment: @Ron:: thanks for the answer, but i don't understand.how do you check collision between the line and the box? and  if you use the line, you still have to check it for each object? that would be still 200*200 = 400000. still 50 times better. i will look it up!

Comment: Where are you getting the 400,000 number? 200 objects have 200 bounding boxes, if you have 200 lines then its 200 * 200 checks, no idea where the 400,000 comes into play? (200*200 = 40,000) https://gist.github.com/ChickenProp/3194723 Raycasting probably isn't the best way to do this, You need to filter down the "possibilities" using something like a bsp-tree first.

Comment: @Ron: Sorry, i didn't mean 400,000 it has to be 40,000. with the link you gave me i should be able to solve this. thanks you very much!